# Solving the Volterra integral equation of the 2nd kind by the method of successive approximations

Tags: integral-equations

I solve the Volterra integral equation of the 2nd kind by the method of successive approximations. Please tell me where I made a mistake in using the `FindSequenceFunction`? Problem: Mathematica returns the data I entered.

```
eq1 = σPhiEnd[ρ] == σPhiBegin[ρ] - 
   Integrate[σPhiBegin[s]*((a^2 - κ*ρ^2)*
      s)/(ρ^2*(a^2 + κ*s^2)), {s, bEnd, ρ}]

K1[ρ_, s_] = s/(a^2 + κ*s^2)

K2[ρ_, s_] = 
 Assuming[{a^2 + s^2 κ > 0, 
   a^2 + κ ρ^2 > 0, ρ > 0, κ > 
    0, ρ != κ, a > 0, s > 0, s - ρ > 0}, 
  Integrate[K1[ρ, t]*K1[t, s], {t, s, ρ}]]

K3[ρ_, s_] = 
 Assuming[{a^2 + s^2 κ > 0, 
   a^2 + κ ρ^2 > 0, ρ > 0, κ > 
    0, ρ != κ, a > 0, s > 0, s - ρ > 0}, 
  Integrate[K2[ρ, t]*K2[t, s], {t, s, ρ}]]

K4[ρ_, s_] = 
 Assuming[{a^2 + s^2 κ > 0, 
   a^2 + κ ρ^2 > 0, ρ > 0, κ > 
    0, ρ != κ, a > 0, s > 0, s - ρ > 0}, 
  Integrate[K3[ρ, t]*K3[t, s], {t, s, ρ}]]

K5[ρ_, s_] = 
 Assuming[{a^2 + s^2 κ > 0, 
   a^2 + κ ρ^2 > 0, ρ > 0, κ > 
    0, ρ != κ, a > 0, s > 0, s - ρ > 0}, 
  Integrate[K4[ρ, t]*K4[t, s], {t, s, ρ}]]

FindSequenceFunction[{K1[ρ, s], K2[ρ, s], 
  K3[ρ, s], K4[ρ, s], K5[ρ, s]}, n]
```

Comment: I decided to separately calculate the formula for the degrees and the coefficient. It worked for the degree, but not for the coefficient(
In[]:= FindSequenceFunction[{0, 1, 3, 7, 15}, n]
Out[]= 1/2 (-2 + 2^n)

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 48, 645120, 42849873690624000}, n]` is a tough nut to crack!

Comment: I believe that this problem cannot be solved without the definition of `σPhiEnd[ρ]`.  Please provide.

Comment: @Mark Could you please define the function `σPhiBegin` and parameter `bEnd`, and add  equation in Latex form that you are trying to solve.